# Importing clojure.contrib.generic.math-functions

Tags: clojure, namespaces, require

I download the clojure 1.2 and clojure-contrib-1.2.0.jar from the [download site](http://clojure.org/downloads).

And I found the info about the [math functions](http://richhickey.github.com/clojure-contrib/generic.math-functions-api.html#clojure.contrib.generic.math-functions/sqrt).

As is shown in the example, I tried to run the code.

```
(ns your-namespace
  (:require clojure.contrib.generic.math-functions))
(println (abs 10))
```

But, I got the following error, when I run as follows.

```
CLOJURE_JAR=/Users/smcho/bin/jar/clojure.jar:/Users/smcho/bin/jar/clojure-contrib-1.2.0.jar
java -cp $CLOJURE_JAR:$CLASSPATH clojure.main SOURCE.CLJ
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: Unable to resolve symbol: abs in this context (hello.clj:4)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:5205)
        ...
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Unable to resolve symbol: abs in this context
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.resolveIn(Compiler.java:5677)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.resolve(Compiler.java:5621)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSymbol(Compiler.java:5584)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:5172)
    ... 25 more
```

What might be wrong?

Comment: Depending on your exact needs, `clojure.contrib.math` might be preferable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `:use` instead of `:require`

```
(ns your-namespace
  (:use clojure.contrib.generic.math-functions))
(println (abs 10))
10
nil
```

Require makes the symbol (abs in this case) available, but you'd have to fully qualify it. Use imports the symbol into "your-namespace":

```
(ns your-namespace2
  (:require clojure.contrib.generic.math-functions))
(println (clojure.contrib.generic.math-functions/abs 10))
10
nil
```

Comment: `:require ... :refer :all` is now preferred over `:use` for Clojure 1.4.0+ libraries  - see: http://dev.clojure.org/display/community/Library+Coding+Standards &  https://github.com/bbatsov/clojure-style-guide